# VBScript : Digitally sign files in the folder throwing error "Cannot find the certificate and private key to use for decryption"

Tags: vbscript, certificate, sign, digital-certificate, mmc

I have created Signer.vbs file for do this functionality and below is the VBScript code to sign all files digitally for particular folder. This folder contains scripting files.

```
Dim sCertificate
Dim sFolder
Dim sStore
Dim objSigner
Dim objFSO
Dim objFolder
Dim colListOfFiles
Dim objFile

sCertificate = "MyCert"
sFolder = "D:\App\Project\VALab\SC\VBSigningProcess\FilesToSign"
sStore = "my"

Set objSigner = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.Signer")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(sFolder)
Set colListOfFiles = objFolder.Files

For Each objFile in colListOfFiles
    WScript.Echo "File Name : " & objFile.Path & vbnewline & "Certificate : " & sCertificate & vbnewline & "Store : " & sStore
    objSigner.SignFile objFile.Path, sCertificate
Next
```

Above code throwing error on below line "Cannot find the certificate and private key to use for decryption, Error Code: 8009200C"

> objSigner.SignFile objFile.Path, sCertificate

"MyCert" certificate located inside MMC. Please review below image.

[image]